# What is the correct data type to map a MySql unsigned BigInt on a Java entity class using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate to map a MySql table to an entity class. Sarting the application, I am experiencing this table\entity mapping error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [id] in table [accomodation]; found [bigint (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [decimal(19,2) (Types#NUMERIC)]
```

So I have the following table named **acccomodation**:

```
Field                                                            Type       Null Key Default    Extra                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                                                               bigint(20) unsigned NO   PRI            auto_increment             
user_id                                                          bigint(20) unsigned NO   MUL                                       
accomodation_name                                                varchar(255) NO                                             
description                                                      text       NO                                             
nation                                                           varchar(255) NO                                             
region                                                           varchar(255) NO                                             
province                                                         varchar(255) NO                                             
city                                                             varchar(255) NO                                             
geographical_position                                            point      NO                                             
stars                                                            int(10)    NO                                             
accomodation_typological_id                                      bigint(20) unsigned YES                                            
accomodation_service_id                                          bigint(20) unsigned YES                                            
tell                                                             varchar(255) YES                                            
mobile                                                           varchar(255) YES                                            
fax                                                              varchar(255) YES                                            
email                                                            varchar(255) YES                                            
time_stamp                                                       datetime   YES
```

The previous table is mapped by this **Accomodation** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accomodation")
public class Accomodation implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private BigInteger id;
    //private Integer id;

    /*@ManyToOne
    private Users users;
    */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accomodation")
    private List<Room> rooms;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String phone;
    private String mobile;
    private String fax;
    private String email;
    private Integer stars;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double latitude;

    // CONSTRUCTOR AND GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
    ...........................................................
    ...........................................................
    ...........................................................

}
```

So, reading the error it seems that exist a mapping error on the **id** field of my **accomodation** table mapped on the related **id** field of the **Accomodation** class.

The problem seems to be that using **BigInteger** as type of the **id** field on the mapped class I have to use **decimal(19,2)** on the **id** field of the table. But I think that it is not good because the primary key of a table should be an **unsigned BigInt** on the DB.

So what Java data type have I to use on my class to correctly map this **unsigned BigInt**?

as you can see in the previous 2 code snippets

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map Mysql type bigint(20) to Java primitive long, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accomodation")
public class Accomodation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
```

However according to [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) you should also be able to use java.math.BigInteger.

My recommendation is to check the version of your driver.